# A convergence problem

Tags: probability, convergence, distributions

Let Xn be a sequence of random variable that converges in distribution to a random variable X, Let Yn be a sequences of random variables with the property that for any finite number c,

```
              P(Yn > c)=1 when n goes infinitely
```

Show that for any finite number c,

```
              P(Xn + Yn >)=1  when n goes infinitely
```

Here is the solution, for all a > 0 there exist N such that if n > N, then P(Xn + Yn > c) > 1−a

Choose N1 such that P(Xn > −m) > 1 − a/2 and N2 such that P(Yn > c + m) > 1 − a/2 Then
P(Xn + Yn > c) ≥ P(Xn > −m, Yn > c + m) ≥ P(Xn > −m) + P(Yn > c + m) − 1 = 1 − a

However, I am confused about why for all a > 0 there exist N such that if n > N, then P(Xn + Yn > c) > 1−a.

Comment: could someone just explain why for all a > 0 there exist N such that if n > N, then P(Xn + Yn > c) > 1−a

Comment: There is the explanation after "Choose $N_1$ such that ...", isn't it?